# Wget - Overwrite files that are different

Tags: wget

So, I'm making an updater for my game using wget. The latest version of the game (with all it's files), is on my server. The thing is that I want wget to download only the files that are different from a directory on the server into the `www` folder in the root of the game files (This has to be recursive, since not all of the game's files are stored directly in that folder). So, when the command is being ran it should check to see if the file's hashsum (if possible, otherwise it should check the size) on the server matches the one in the game's files. If it doesn't, it should download the file from the server and replace the one in the game's directory. This way, the player won't have to re-download all of the game's files.

Here's the command I used for testing:

```
wget.exe -N -r ftp://10.42.0.1/gamupd/arpg -O ./www
```

The server is running on my local network, so I use that IP address.
The thing is that it doesn't save the contents of `/gamupd/arpg` to the `www` folder, instead it seems to copy the directory tree of `arpg`.

Comment: I believe you'll need a bash script for that.

Comment: Cool story, but I don't see a question there. Have you tried the wget manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `timestamping` flag will satisfy you. From `wget -help`:

> -N,  --timestamping              don't re-retrieve files unless newer than
>                                        local

Comment: Not sure if it works, but the command I used didn't store to the proper directory. I just updated my question.